# C-c c does not activate Org Capture after upgrading to Emacs 29.2

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, org-capture

After upgrading to Emacs 29.2 I can't activate Org capture using 'C-c c'. In the mini buffer it says 'C-c c is undefined'
I can activate Org capture using 'M-x org-capture', but I preffer the 'C-c c' option.

In my init.el file I have the following configuration:

```
 (global-set-key (kbd "C-c l") 'org-store-link)
 (global-set-key (kbd "C-c a") 'org-agenda)
 (global-set-key (kbd "C-c c") 'org-capture)
```

After looking at the documentation https://orgmode.org/org.html#Activation I changed it to the following:

```
 (global-set-key (kbd "C-c l") #'org-store-link)
 (global-set-key (kbd "C-c a") #'org-agenda)
 (global-set-key (kbd "C-c c") #'org-capture)
```

Either way, non of the above configurations works. I have checked through the rest of the init.el configuration and as far as I can see there is no other conflicting key bindings to 'C-c c'

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by moving the three global-set-key configurations to the beginning of the init.el

Comment: Sounds like you have an error in your init file. This would cause code after the error to not be executed. Try running emacs with the `--debug-init` options to pinpoint where the error is and what type of error it is.